# Catching runtime errors in Perl and converting to exceptions

Tags: perl, runtime-error

Perl currently implements `$SIG{__DIE__}` in such a way that it will catch any error that occurs, even inside eval blocks. This has a really useful property that you can halt the code at the exact point where the error occurs, collect a stack trace of the actual error, wrap this up in an object, and then call die manually with this object as the parameter.

This abuse of `$SIG{__DIE__}` is deprecated. Officially, you are supposed to replace `$SIG{__DIE__}` with `*CORE::GLOBAL::die`. However, these two are **NOT** remotely equivalent. `*CORE::GLOBAL::die` is **NOT** called when a runtime error occurs! All it does is replace explicit calls to `die()`.

I am not interested in replacing die.

I am specifically interested in catching runtime errors.

I need to ensure that any runtime error, in any function, at any depth, in any module, causes Perl to pass control to me so that I can collect the stack trace and rethrow. This needs to work inside an eval block -- one or more enclosing eval blocks may want to catch the exception, but the runtime error could be in a function without an enclosing eval, inside any module, from anywhere.

`$SIG{__DIE__}` supports this perfectly—and has served me faithfully for a couple of years or more—but the Powers that Be™ warn that this fantastic facility may be snatched away at any time, and I don't want a nasty surprise one day down the line.

Ideally, for Perl itself, they could create a new signal `$SIG{__RTMERR__}` for this purpose (switching signal is easy enough, for me anyway, as it's only hooked in one place). Unfortunately, my persuasive powers wouldn't lead an alcoholic to crack open a bottle, so assuming this will not happen, how exactly is one supposed to achieve this aim of catching runtime errors cleanly?

(For example, another answer here recommends Carp::Always, which … also hooks DIE!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it.  I've done it.  Probably everyone who's aware of this hook has done it.

It's *Perl*; it's still compatible going back decades.  I interpret "deprecated" here to mean "please don't use this if you don't need it, ew, gross".  But you do need it, and seem to understand the implications, so imo go for it.  I seriously doubt an irreplaceable language feature is going away any time soon.

And release your work on CPAN so the next dev doesn't need to reinvent this yet again.  :)

Comment: It's been deprecated for years, but thus far, no replacement has been stated. This either means that it's not deprecated, or that they don't intend to retain the functionality, or that they've simply neglected to state the correct approach. You can't deprecate something important if it's the only way to achieve something! Maybe they won't ...

Comment: According to [a search on grep.cpan.me](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=__DIE__[%27%22]%3F\}+*%3D) "more than 1000 distributions" are using `$SIG{__DIE__}`. I don't think it will ever go...